# How to sum of column by depending other column in my sql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json, sum

how to calculate / SUM of column by the latest data of updateid column ?

I try this :

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

```
SELECT 
ANY_VALUE(code) AS code,
COUNT(*) AS total_rows,
SUM(data->'$.chart."21"') AS total_a
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY code;
```

[image: from the query abore, it sums all in rows]

From above query it sums all rows, it should be sum the latest update id

anyone can solve this problem ?

here is the fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qHnaHNQtEhDasLiSB4Jhv5/0

Comment: Show desured output. Specify MySQL version.

Comment: the code "LKJER" sould be 12 as it has the latest update id, I use mysql version 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t1.code,
COUNT(*) AS total_rows,
SUM(t1.data->'$.chart."21"') AS total_a
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(updateid) AS updateid
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY code) AS t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
                          AND t1.updateid = t2.updateid
GROUP BY t1.code
ORDER BY t1.code;
```

Comment: I am new in mysql, so it looks so complex, but it works :), thanks .

Comment: I have another problems, how to sum mr.a score by the latest update id, mr_a_score should be 40, look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qHnaHNQtEhDasLiSB4Jhv5/4

Comment: it should be sum by the latest updateid . https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qHnaHNQtEhDasLiSB4Jhv5/5

Comment: @Akina - I afraid it will return count(*) different from expected result provided in question, here subquery in select list could work

Comment: @broid Add subquery which selects last records only.

Comment: @a_vlad You're right. If this value is needed really (and I am not sure in that), JOIN must be converted to cartesian, and join condition must be moved to CASE condition of output list expression.

Comment: Ok, but I need to Google about subquery first 